# Error handling for division by zero

Tags: php, codeigniter, error-handling

Using code in codeigniter, php:

```
class test extends CI_Controller {
    public function index(){
        eval( '$amt = (' . $arithmetic_formula . ');' );
    }
}
```

getting error:

> Warning Message: Division by zero

The variable `$arithmetic_formula` is a dynamic formula which can be change by the user anytime. And sometime we are having zero in the formula in which we don't have any control, that's why we are getting the error.
How can I deal with the above error, please help if anyone knows.
Thanks in advance !

Comment: The error says it all, you need to parse the `$arithmetic_formula` string serching for that division. Btw using eval is not a good idead for security reasons

Comment: Love a bit of eval on a monday. Just check that the value before division isn't 0..

Comment: Eval is Evil ! Why don't you use a return instead ? anyway, you can use an If statement or a Try catch  to fix this.

Comment: What @teeyo say's, try/catch the eval function and check value's before using them.

Comment: If you insist on using `eval` go ahead an use a `try-catch` clause.

Comment: Use try and catch for this

Comment: @Nigel Ren
I have seen the post on which behalf you have marked my question as duplicate but As I can see that post I am not getting the answer from there.

Comment: @claudio The `$arithmetic_formula` is dynamic and can have any number of brackets and arithmetic operators and including some defined variables. And this make it more difficult to parse it.
Example Original Formula: `($a + $b) - ($c + $d) / ($e * $f) `
After value evaluated: `(1 + 2) - (3 + 4 ) / (5 * 0) `

Comment: @teeyo try catch is not working with eval()

Comment: @RohitGusain you're right, I didn't know that ... just another reason not use eval :)

Comment: Pop an @ symbol in front of eval and you'll be good to go ;)